# How to SET sqlplus params using python subprocess?

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to set some params for a single sqlplus process and run a query to get an html op file

```
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','abc/abc'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    session.stdin.write(' SET MARKUP HTML ON ')
    session.stdin.write(' SPOOL op.html')
    session.stdin.write(' select sysdate from dual;')
    session.stdin.write(' exit;')


    stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
```

But I always get some error like

```
Usage: SET MARKUP HTML [ON|OFF] [HEAD text] [BODY text]
 [TABLE text] [ENTMAP {ON|OFF}] [SPOOL {ON|OFF}] [PRE[FORMAT] {ON|OFF}]
```

or

```
SP2-0158: unknown SET option &quot;;spool&quot;
```

Do i need to create process 1 for SET MARKUP HTML ON and pipe its output to SPOOL op.html  coz it works properly in sqlplus.

Comment: How about `session.stdin.write(' SET MARKUP HTML ON \n')`. It has actually concatenated all yours individual command as one line.

Comment: When I do that I the file op.html is ALWAYS BLANK ... WHY?